# ClassCastException while dynamically loading a class in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, classloader, classcastexception

I have a thread that loads different classes for the resources it needs depending on the specific implementation of the system. My implementation is on Android and I have a class that returns the specific classes needed by my implementation. I seem to be able to load the class fine, but when I try to assign it to the object in my main thread, it gives me a ClassCastException. Here are the snippets:

In my main thread, I do:

```
    try {
        grammarProcessor = config.loadObject(GrammarProcessor.class);
```

which gives me this stacktrace:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(6682): FATAL EXCEPTION: JVoiceXmlMain
    E/AndroidRuntime(6682): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jvoicexml.android.JVoiceXmlGrammarProcessor
    E/AndroidRuntime(6682):     at org.jvoicexml.JVoiceXmlMain.run(JVoiceXmlMain.java:321)
```

`GrammarProcessor` is an interface and `JVoiceXmlGrammarProcessor` is the class that I load and implements that interface. The loading code is as follows:

```
else if(baseClass == GrammarProcessor.class){
        String packageName = "org.jvoicexml.android";
        String className = "org.jvoicexml.android.JVoiceXmlGrammarProcessor";           
        String apkName = null;
        Class<?> handler = null;
        T b = null;

        try {
            PackageManager manager = callManagerContext.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo info= manager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            apkName= info.sourceDir;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        PathClassLoader myClassLoader =
            new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(
                    apkName,
                    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        try {
            handler = Class.forName(className, true, myClassLoader);
            return (T) handler.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }           
        catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

When debugging, I check what's returning from the load method and it is an object with an id number. If I click on it, it'll say `org.jvoicexml.android.JVoiceXmlGrammarProcessor@40565820`, and the dropdown will show the two private fields that a `JVoiceXmlGrammarProcessor` should have, so it looks like it's well loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: grammarProcessor variable is of class GrammarProcessor.class??

Comment: Had you tried to use `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` instead of instantinating new `PathClassLoader` ?

Comment: @Marakatu Wait, I'm super confused. What are you trying to do exactly? Return a Class<?> object by name? Use `Class.forName`. On Android, you only ever need to use new classloaders if you want to load classes from a separate .dex file ([here's a good article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html)). Please explain what you're trying to do. Edit: Are you loading from the same apk or a different one?

Answer (score 12):

I think I understand what's happening here but I have to make an assumption that `org.jvoicexml.android` is *not* your package, i.e., you're loading from a different apk (as the bounty seems to suggest).

With that in mind, this is impossible and for a good reason.

Let's start with your own app - you have the type `GrammarProcessor` available from your own `classes.dex` and into your default ClassLoader (the `PathClassLoader` that you get when the zygote forks your process). Let's call this type `GP1`. Any class in your own application that implements `GrammarProcessor` actually has `GP1` in their interface list.

Then, you instantiate a new classloader. If you look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2.0-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/PathClassLoader.java), you'll see that `PathClassLoader` is just a thin wrapper around [`BaseDexClassLoader`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2.0-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader.java) which in turn delegates to a [`DexPathList`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2.0-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexPathList.java), which in turn delegates to [`DexFile`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2.0-release/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexFile.java) objects which in turn do the loading in native code. Phew.

There's a subtle part of `BaseDexClassLoader` that's the cause of your troubles but if you haven't seen it before, you might miss it:

```
this.pathList = new DexPathList(this, dexPath, libraryPath, optimizedDirectory);
```

and a bit further down:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class c = pathList.findClass(name);
    if (c == null) {
        ...
    }
    return c;
}
```

**BaseDexClassLoader does not check with its parent first!**

.. and that in short is your problem.

More precisely, the `DexPathList` and `DexFile` inside it load all the classes from the other `dex` and never look into the classes already loaded in the VM.

So, you end up with two different loaded versions of `GrammarProcessor`. Then, the object you're instantiating is referring to the new `GP2` class, while you're trying to cast it to `GP1`. Obviously impossible.

Is there a solution to this?

There's one that's been done before, but you won't like it. Facebook [use it](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920) in their app to load a bunch of `dex` files with strong relationships between them. (It's there, before all the messing about with `LinearAlloc`):

> we examined the Android source code and used Java reflection to directly modify some of its internal structures

I'm 90% sure they get the `PathClassLoader` that you're given (`getSystemClassLoader()`), get the `DexPathList` and override the `dexElements` private field to have an extra `Element` with the other dex file (apk in your case). Hacky as hell and I would advise against it.

It just occurred to me that if you don't want to use the newly loaded classes in a way that the framework sees them, you could extend from `BaseDexClassLoader` and implement the proper look-in-parent-before-trying-to-load behaviour. I haven't done it, so I can't promise it will work.

My advice? Just use remote services. This is what `Binder` is meant for. Alternatively, rethink your apk separation.

Comment: That was extremely informative and good insides into the inner workings of the ClassLoader and the suggestion seem viable (not the FB hack). My situation, and maybe somewhat related to the OPs as well is that I have an application which I want to "sell" extensions but the extensions need to go beyond what AIDL is capable of doing, primarily working with non Parcelable objects. So what I would like to do is bring large parts of the application (such as full functioning fragments, which I have for the most part gotten to work with the exception of interacting with the current loaded classes).

Comment: The issue now is: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation`

Comment: Ah, `dexopt`, I was afraid it was going to do something weird. Since you're essentially overwriting a class in the loaded dex, all references that have been pre-verified by the compiler have become invalid. It would take someone more knowledgeable than me to even begin getting around that (though I'm afraid it might be entirely impossible). My first suggestion is to try the FB hack and prepend the other dex, making sure to only ever load the foreign interface, not your own.

Comment: Also, @J.Romero, thinking more about your fragments, the resources are the other huge barrier - how on earth are you going to access them from a different package?

Comment: Thank you for everything `dexopt` seems to be the major blocker. Resources were actually the easier part so if the fragment was self dependent there would have not been a problem. Here's what I did, I might add a sample app to show the full implementation later: https://gist.github.com/jromero/6099470

Comment: Ah, of course. Do you need shared user between the packages or does it work otherwise? There's also CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE, might want to see what that does - I think it might actually be relevant to your case.

Comment: You can access Resources from another apk using the packageName (from Manifest) like: `createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY).getResources();` Note that I don't know what kind of vulnerability IGNORE_SECURITY introduces and if you could make it work without that flag..